# Sequelize Associations - Association Table

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I'm working with **Sequelize**, **PostgreSQL** and **Node JS**.

I've designed my database like this:

1. Table A => *ID is autoincremented*
2. Table B => *ID is autoincremented*
3. Table C => *ID is autoincremented*
4. Table Association => *ID is autoincremented*

In the Association table I add foreign keys for Table A, Table B and Table C ID's.

So the Association table looks something like this:

`| id | tableA_id | tableB_id | tableC_id |`

Table **A** Associations:

```
Table A => Has **Many** Table **B**.

Table A => Has **Many** Table **C**.
```

Table **B** Associations:

```
Table B => Has **One** Table **A**.

Table B => Has **Many** Table **C**.
```

Table **C** Associations:

```
Table C => Has **One** Table **A**.

Table C => Has **One** Table **B**.
```

This being said, I have this associations in sequelize:

```
 TableAssociationModel.hasMany(TableAModel, {
    as: 'TableAModel',
    foreignKey: 'tableA_id',
    targetKey: 'tableA_id',
  });
  TableAssociationModel.hasMany(TableBModel, {
    as: 'TableBModel',
    foreignKey: 'tableB_id',
    targetKey: 'tableB_id',
  });

  TableAssociationModel.hasMany(TableCModel, {
    as: 'TableCModel',
    foreignKey: 'tableC_id',
    targetKey: 'tableC_id',
  });
```

Database example:

```
| id | tableA_id | tableB_id | tableC_id |
|  1 |     2     |      1    |      1    |
|  2 |     2     |      1    |      2    |
|  3 |     2     |      2    |      3    |
```

If I searched for Table C ID = 1, I would get my associations, but if I searched for ID = 2, nether Table A or Table B data where passed.

Also, I search in my Tables (A, B and C), and want to return my associations in Table Association.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance and I hope I explained myself good enough, any doubt please let me know, really want to understand how this works.

PS: I'm a junior, don't be to harsh xD

Comment: Could you please provide sequelize query code and generated sql query?

Comment: @Mansur thank you for the availability, I have corrected the issue, will add the solution below, in case anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out:

```
TableAModel.hasMany(TableAssociationModel, {
    as: 'relationsData',
    foreignKey: 'tableA_id',
    sourceKey: 'tableA_id',
  });
  
TableAssociationModel.belongsTo(TableAModel, {
    as: 'tableAData',
    foreignKey: 'tableA_id',
    sourceKey: 'tableA_id',
  });

 TableBModel.hasMany(TableAssociationModel, {
    as: 'relationsData',
    foreignKey: 'tableB_id',
    sourceKey: 'tableB_id',
  });

  TableAssociationModel.belongsTo(TableBModel, {
    as: 'tableBData',
    foreignKey: 'tableB_id',
    sourceKey: 'tableB_id',
  });

  TableCModel.hasMany(TableAssociationModel, {
    as: 'relationsData',
    foreignKey: 'tableC_id',
    sourceKey: 'tableC_id',
  });

  TableAssociationModel.belongsTo(TableCModel, {
    as: 'tableCData',
    foreignKey: 'tableC_id',
    targetKey: 'tableC_id',
  });
```

My associations where only 1 way and were wrongly done.

Figured out that even though I want to search in the **TableAssociationModel**, my main models were Table A, B and C, so I needed to treat them as the more important and tell Sequelize that they are the main.

Btw, if you want to see the query generated in Sequelize you can use:

```
DEBUG=sequelize* node ***your/file.js***
```

***your/file.js*** <= the file where you use for example:

```
TableAModel.findAll({

})
```